# Create a link to a Word document from an Excel cell using a relative path

Tags: excel, ms-word

In an Excel cell, I want to link to a MS Word file, e.g. to `C:\MyFile\someDoc.docx`, using a relative path.

My Excel file is in the folder `C:\MyFile`. So my path should be something like `currentdirectory\someDoc.docx`  so that I can mail the whole `C:\MyFile` folder or transfer it somewhere else.

How can I do that?

I am aware how to link with an absolute path like `C:\MyFile\someDoc.docx` but what if I transfer the Excel file to somebody. In the destination folder, will it still search for the `C:\MyFile` location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the location of your workbook using the `CELL` function.

Enter the below formula in your sheet, say in cell `B1`,

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
```

This will give you the root folder in which your workbook is present. Now in the cell in which you have the link to the `docx` file, use the below formula,

```
 =HYPERLINK(B1&"someDoc.docx","Click here")
```

Hope this helps. Even if you move the folder, this will work.

Comment: What should be there in A1? . B1 cannot be used for any other purpose?

Comment: A1 can be empty.. Yes B1 will just contain the root folder address. If you want you can change to some other cell

Comment: Can that be written as one statement i.e getting the root dir and link i.e =LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)   and =HYPERLINK(B1&"someDoc.docx","Click here")  so that I do not need a different cell for getting the current dir info

Comment: yes you can, replace the B1 with the formula. It should work

Comment: Thank u so much Shiva